# Getting an item using Powershell having only the URL

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell, urls

Is it possible to get a Sitecore item via Powershell script having only the public URL?

Something like an overload of the Get-Item function that receives the URL would be ideal

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can get item by URL using below function. You may have to tweak it for resolving wildcard items.

```
function GetItemByUrl($url){
    $url = [System.Uri]::new($url);

    $siteContext = [Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextFactory]::GetSiteContext($url.Host, $url.PathAndQuery);

    $homePath = $siteContext.StartPath;
    if (!$homePath.EndsWith("/")){            
        $homePath += "/";
    }

    $itemPath = [Sitecore.MainUtil]::DecodeName($url.AbsolutePath);

    if ($itemPath.StartsWith($siteContext.VirtualFolder)){
        $itemPath = $itemPath.Remove(0, $siteContext.VirtualFolder.Length);
    }

    $fullPath = $homePath + $itemPath;
    return $siteContext.Database.GetItem($fullPath);
}

$item = GetItemByUrl("http://localhost.sc/my-page")

Write-Host $item.ID
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good but what if the item is inside a bucket?

Comment: For that, you can check how Sitecore resolves URLs for bucket items, and then you can tweak the method accordingly.